# How to check if a regex groups are equal?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

I have a RegEx that checks my string. In my string I have two groups `?<key>` and `?<value>`. So here is my sample string:

```
string input = "key=value&key=value1&key=value2";
```

I use `MatchCollections` and when I try to print my groups on the console that here is my code:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

foreach (Match item in matches)
{
    Console.Write("{0}=[{1}]",item.Groups["key"], item.Groups["value"]);
}
```

I get an output like this: **`key=[value]key=[value1]key=[value2]`**

But I want my output to be like this: **`key=[value, value1, value2]`**

My point is how to check the group "`key`" if it's equal to the previous one so I can make the output like that I want.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In a Java world, I guess I would store in a ``Map<Key, List<Value>>`` and then generate a string based on this map. I suppose what you are asking is beyond the scope of Regex and that you will have some processing to do, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes. I want to print it on the console and to look like an Dictionary 

"Key" = ["value", "value1", "value2"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`:

```
string pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (Match item in matches)
{
    if (!results.ContainsKey(item.Groups["key"].Value)) {
        results.Add(item.Groups["key"].Value, new List<string>());
    }
    results[item.Groups["key"].Value].Add(item.Groups["value"].Value);
}

foreach (var r in results) {
    Console.Write("{0}=[{1}]", r.Key, string.Join(", ", r.Value));
}
```

Note the use of `string.Join` to output the data in the format required.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

Something like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();

foreach (Match item in matches)
{
    var key = item.Groups["key"];
    var val = item.Groups["value"];
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) 
    {
        dict[key] = new List<string>();
    }
    dict[key].Add(val);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq `GroupBy` method:

```
string input = "key=value&key=value1&key=value2&key1=value3&key1=value4";
string pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

foreach (var result in matches
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .GroupBy(k => k.Groups["key"].Value, v => v.Groups["value"].Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}=[{1}]", result.Key, String.Join(",", result));
}
```

Output for snippet (here I've added another key `key1` with two values into you original input string):

```
key=[value,value1,value2]
key1=[value3,value4]
```